# WooCommerce, мультисайтовость и суб.домены

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Вопрос следующего характера, как лучше всего реализовать для магазина мультисайтовость с суб.доменами для каждого региона?

Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итак:

1. Если требуется персонализировать главную и иметь возможность
   редактировать товар, цены и прочее отдельно?
2. Если меняются только некоторые надписи?

Знаю, что в первом случае можно клонировать проект и связать все это дело. Во втором случае, как и с языками, можно использовать какой-нить плагин или встроенную мультисайтовость.

В общем, кто сталкивался, дайте совет пожалуйста. Интересует наиболее простой вариант дальнейшего управления.

Comment: Всё же нужно как-то определиться что нужно - первый или второй вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Мультисайтовость убивает WooCommerce, если только вы не захотите приобрести сильно платный ($200 - $300) плагин WooCommerce Multistore.

Без этого плагина вам придётся поддерживать отдельную базу товаров на каждом сайте сети, что вряд ли может служить хорошим решением.

Попробуйте сделать всё на одном сайте с помощью плагина [Multiple Domain](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/). Он позволяет отобразить информацию на нескольких доменах, как в вашем случае. При этом WordPress по сути остаётся тем же сайтом на одиночном домене.

Дальше вы можете модифицировать вывод нужной вам информации (строки) на основе того, где вы находитесь (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`). Для коррекции ассортимента и цен надо использовать соответствующие хуки WooCommerce.

Comment: А как насчет [данного плагина](https://codecanyon.net/item/woo-multisite-product-category-sync/19560922)?

Comment: Ну ОК, синхронизуете товары на сайтах сети. А дальше? Как заставить выводить разные цены?

Comment: Это вы говорите про первый вопрос. Для него - да, необходим  Multistore plugin, хотя, для такой задачи я бы скорее всего расширил бюджет и смотрел в сторону Magento, а не это вот все) А что по поводу изменения только надписей или главной, без изменения каталога?

Comment: Я вам дал ответ, который решает ваши вопросы. И надписи можно менять, и товарам цены разные назначать в зависимости от сайта. Можно и "данный плагин" за $19 использовать. Но все равно манипуляции с ценами - через хуки цен WooCommerce и `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`